# When is it acceptable to use self-sign cert in production?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

Self signed cert is always looked down as a test-only certificate. But as per understating, using it for production is perfectly fine if used for the right reason. I am trying to provide some guidelines to my customers about that to use what. E.g.:

1. **Authentication**: Not ok to use self-signed as the Brower will not trust the "self" issuer. So, for service-to-service or service-to-client authentication is not ok to use self-signed. Unless there is a pre thumbprint/CN whitelisting process before verifying. Lot of people do these, e.g. Azure where I upload the management cert public key, which is used to authenticate their API.
2. **Signing**: No ok, as there is no trust with the issuer. Unless there is a pre thumbprint whitelisting process before verifying. Unless there is a pre thumbprint/CN whitelisting process before verifying.
3. **Encryption**: Perfectly OK to use self-signed as there no chain trust required. In case of an attack, the MIM cert will simply not decrypt, no other impact.

Comment: But why would you want to use a self-signed cert in the first place? There are no advantages vs. a trusted CA signed cert.

Comment: CA signed costs money, my customer generates 20000+ certs, so they save a lot of money. That's why.

Comment: [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certs are out of the question?

Comment: I think this question would fit better into https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Case (3) is not 'perfectly OK'. In the case of an attack, if the MITM certificate ends up being trusted, the peer will end up being trusted, and SSL will terminate at the attacker, with plaintext being visible to him. Certificates do not perform or participate in SSL encryption or decryption. This is not a separate threat model from '(1) Authentication'.

Comment: @EJP: How is that a valid argument? The goal is encryption is data hiding, irrespective of what the cert type is (CA signed or self-signed), if the attacker gets the cert, he decrypts and see the data in plain text. SSL is not in the picture of this schema (i talked about SSL in Case (1), which is authentication). If the MiTM cert is a cert different of the original one, it will simply fail decryption (no point of it being trusted or not). Public-key encryption used its keys to for EFS, data encryption for transit etc (and not necessary the cert).

Comment: @Bhaskar Getting hold of the certificate is nothing. It's a public document. The attacker *provides* the certificate, and that's what makes him the man in the middle. Otherwise there is no MITM attack. Why would he provide one he didn't have the private key for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Authentication: Not ok to use self-signed as the Brower will not trust the "self" issuer.

OK to use as long as there is a trusted offline certificate distribution process. Not OK to use via 'trust-all' code.

> Signing: No ok, as there is no trust with the issuer.

OK to use as long as there is a trusted offline certificate distribution process.

> Encryption: Perfectly OK to use self-signed as there no chain trust required. In case of an attack, the MIM cert will simply not decrypt, no other impact.

OK to use as long as there is a trusted offline certificate distribution process. The part about 'MI[T]M cert will simply not decrypt' is meaningless. Certificates don't perform decryption, and a MITM who has managed to provide his own certificate instead of the target's will have the corresponding private key, otherwise the attack is pointless. In the absence of trust, if the sender uses the public key out of an untrusted certificate to encrypt anything, he doesn't know who can decrypt it, so he is being insecure.

Comment: @EJB For the primitive encryption construct there is no MiTM, for example the implementation of PKCS#7/CMS/(S/MIME) EnvelopedData , its uses it creates the session key (symmetric key) and encrypts it with the cert public key. And decrypt with the session key decryption with private key. So, i can use a self-sign for this. SSL as i mentioned in case I needs CA sign, unless its white listed. For e.g. MS Azure, I upload the public key and then  I use that cert to auth all REST calls. For that self-sign is fine too, as a MiTM thumbprint is not white listed.

Comment: @Bhaskar No. As I said in my comment above two days ago, the MITM attack functions by supplying his certificate instead of the proper one. You can only use a self-signed certificate if you take precautions against this attack, i.e. organize some sort of trust for it, which is easiest done by having it CA-signed. Merely acquiring someone else's certificate does not constitute any kind of MITM attack. The MITM is pretending to be the peer, by definition. He is more than a mere snooper.

Answer (score 1):

I can find several real examples where a trusted CA is not really needed

- VPN: Certificates for server and clients
- SSL/TLS client authentication: certificates for client authentication when mutual authentication is required
- SSL/TLS in private networks: internal services or servers farms
- asymmetric encryption: only keys are really needed, not the certificate.
- sign & auth in a closed environment: Like the employees of an organization using a cryptographic token issued by abprivate CA
- message authentication between services: SOAP signing, JWT or SAML messages. The receiver part includes the server signing certificate in its truststore explictly to validate signer identity

Comment: All of these resolve to one case: the peer can be made to trust the self-signed certificate via some offline process.

Comment: Exactly @EJP,  trusting in the issuer a private Certificate Authority can perfectly replace a known "trusted" CA in any of the scenarios, sign, auth or encryption. My list are real cases where they are used